# error when update , MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test

i got error message : Line: 60, Column: 1
System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []

can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code below?

here is my code

```
public String picklistVal;
PYEMPPAYPERIOD__c[] empPayPeriod = [SELECT Period__r.Element_Name__r.Budget_Item_Code__c, Employee_No__r.Company_Name__r.Id, Period__r.Element_Name__r.Element_Group__c, 
                                        Period__r.Element_Name__r.Id, Period__r.Element_Name__r.Element_Type__c, Period__r.Element_Name__r.Content_Value__c, Employee_No__r.Id, 
                                        Period__r.Element_Name__r.End_Date__c, Period__r.Element_Name__r.Group_Display__c, Period__r.Element_Name__r.Group_Order__c,
                                        Period__r.Element_Name__r.Is_Value__c, Period__r.Period__r.Id, Period__r.Element_Name__r.Process_Sequence_ID__c, 
                                        Period__r.Element_Name__r.Start_Date__c FROM PYEMPPAYPERIOD__c WHERE Period__r.Period__r.Id =:'a0t41000000QeKg'];
PYEMPELEMENT__c[] empElement = new PYEMPELEMENT__c[]{};
PYEMPELEMENT__c e = new PYEMPELEMENT__c();
for(PYEMPPAYPERIOD__c pp : empPayPeriod) {
        e = new PYEMPELEMENT__c();
        e.Budget_Item_Code__c = pp.Period__r.Element_Name__r.Budget_Item_Code__c;
        e.Company_Name__c = pp.Employee_No__r.Company_Name__r.Id;
        e.Element_Group__c = pp.Period__r.Element_Name__r.Element_Group__c;
        e.Element_Name__c = pp.Period__r.Element_Name__r.Id;
        e.Element_Type__c = pp.Period__r.Element_Name__r.Element_Type__c;
        e.Element_Value__c = pp.Period__r.Element_Name__r.Content_Value__c;
        e.Employee_No__c = pp.Employee_No__r.Id;
        e.End_Date__c = pp.Period__r.Element_Name__r.End_Date__c;
        e.Group_Display__c = pp.Period__r.Element_Name__r.Group_Display__c;
        e.Group_Order__c = pp.Period__r.Element_Name__r.Group_Order__c;
        e.Is_Value__c = pp.Period__r.Element_Name__r.Is_Value__c;
        e.Period__c = pp.Period__r.Period__r.Id;
        e.Process_Sequence_ID__c = pp.Period__r.Element_Name__r.Process_Sequence_ID__c;
        e.Start_Date__c = pp.Period__r.Element_Name__r.Start_Date__c;
        e.Value_Result__c = pp.Period__r.Element_Name__r.Content_Value__c;

        e.Process_Flag__c = 2;

            empElement.add(e);}    

//looping for compare field Employee No, Start Date Element Name
        for(PYEMPELEMENT__c empPP : empElement){
        String v1 = empPP.Employee_No__c;
        String v2 = empPP.Element_Name__c;
        Date v3 = empPP.Start_Date__c;
        Decimal v4 = empPP.Element_Value__c;

        PYEMPELEMENT__c[] compareF = [SELECT Employee_No__c, Element_Name__c, Start_Date__c FROM PYEMPELEMENT__c WHERE Employee_No__c =: v1 
                                     AND Element_Name__c =: v2 AND Start_Date__c =: v3];
        PYEMPELEMENT__c compF = new PYEMPELEMENT__c();

        System.debug(compareF);
        if(compareF != NULL){
            //System.debug(v1);
            PYEMPELEMENT__c updt = new PYEMPELEMENT__c();
            updt.Id = compF.Id;
            updt.Element_Value__c = empPP.Element_Value__c;
            updt.Value_Result__c = empPP.Value_Result__c;
            update updt;
            }

         else
             insert empElement;                  
    }

    system.debug(empElement);
```

Comment: While it won't affect the error in question, you should ***never query or perform dml in a loop***. Query before your loop, aggregate the records to operate on, and perform your dml after the loop.

Comment: i'm doing the looping because i want to check from sf database , if already have the same record, just update it, but to make sure the record is same, it was dependent on 3 fields, which is : Employee No, Start Date, and Element Name. 
do u get it? what i want to do? @AdrianLarson

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing this:

```
updt.Id = compF.Id;
```

But compF was created without assigning it an Id. So if moving thatId to updt, updt also will not have an Id.
Then when updating updt, there will be no Id in the record so nothing to update.

You might want to describe the actual goal you are trying to achieve..

If you want to update the record found in the SOQL query with the values in empPP, then you can do that within the if loop. No need for compF in between:

```
for(PYEMPELEMENT__c empPP : empElement){
        String v1 = empPP.Employee_No__c;
        String v2 = empPP.Element_Name__c;
        Date v3 = empPP.Start_Date__c;
        Decimal v4 = empPP.Element_Value__c;
        PYEMPELEMENT__c[] compareF = [SELECT Employee_No__c, Element_Name__c, Start_Date__c FROM PYEMPELEMENT__c WHERE Employee_No__c =: v1 
                                 AND Element_Name__c =: v2 AND Start_Date__c =: v3];
        // you don't need this PYEMPELEMENT__c compF = new PYEMPELEMENT__c();

        // prepare a placeholder for any records that need to be inserted new
        List<PYEMPELEMENT__c> fToInsert = new List<PYEMPELEMENT__c>();

        System.debug(compareF);
        if(!compareF.isEmpty()){ // better to check if list is empty instead of checking for null
            //System.debug(v1);
            PYEMPELEMENT__c updt = new PYEMPELEMENT__c();
            updt.Id = compareF[0].Id; // just assign the first query result's id (as you expect only 1 result in the query anyway)
            updt.Element_Value__c = empPP.Element_Value__c;
            updt.Value_Result__c = empPP.Value_Result__c;
            update updt;
         }
        else {
             fToInsert.add(); 
         }
}
insert fToInsert;
```

> BUT THEN! you still have a query inside a loop, which is unforgiveable
>   in Salesforce! Search around on the boards for some help on that. And
>   when you get stuck, I'd advice to post a new question on this board
>   (to avoid confusion and mixup with the already provided answers)

Comment: Ah, I misread `compF` as an element of `compareF`.

Comment: hmm, oke then, so how to solve this one? (assigning Id into compF, so updt can have the compFId)?

so all i want is, before i insert an record into salesforce, i want to check the new record first, is the new record already stored in sf database or not? to check the record is same or not, it was dependent on 3 fields, which is : Employee No, Start Date, and Element Name. if that 3 field all same, then, just update it, else insert new record into sf database. 
@Guy

Comment: OK tnx, I updated my answer according the this.

Comment: hmm, it can updated (in case when already have the same record), but cant add new record. It means, i delete my record on sf database, then i execute my code, then error message popup :
Line: 55, Column: 1
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0 with id a1541000000om61AAA; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an insert call: [Id]
the pict : http://prntscr.com/ckivdu
@Guy

how to insert the record, if the record is not exist on my sf database? (through my condition If else, if same, update , else insert) when insert, it was error

Comment: you are doing insert empElement inside the loop, while empElement is a list of records. You probably want to insert only empPP (the current record that cannot be matched). I've updated my answer a little bit to reflect this.

Comment: thanks @Guy! the answer : in my if else, my else statement must insert e; hahha it solved now! thanks alot!